# Update UI using Custom Hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to work with custom hooks and I have also implemented a custom hook, but I am having problems performing delete operation and fetch users again scenarios.

Users are fetched fine the first time but how can I handle the delete user and fetch users again scenarios and show loaders whenever API is in progress?

I might be using the App component wrongly. Can anyone please help me fix this issue that how can I achieve the desired results?

Thanks

Code:

```
export interface APIStatus {
  status: 'loading' | 'error' | 'done';
}

export const useFetch = (api, params) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [apiStatus, setApiStatus] = useState<APIStatus>({ status: 'loading' });
  const [isSignedIn] = getSignInStatus();

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const {data} = await api(params);
      setData(data);
    } catch (err) {
      setApiStatus({ status: 'error' });
    } finally {
      setApiStatus({ status: 'done' });
    }
  }, [api]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSignedIn) fetchData();
  }, [isSignedIn]);

  return { apiStatus, data };
};

//App.tsx
export const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { apiStatus, data } = useFetch(apis.fetchUsers, "limit=100");

  const deleteUser = (id) => {
    const { apiStatus, data } = useFetch(apis.deleteUser, `id=${id}`);
    // 1. apiStatus is only available inside. I cannot access it in return and show loader

    if (data.status){
      // 2. How can I call the fetchUsers API again as I cannot call the useFetch hook inside if block
    }
  }

  return(
    <>
      {apiStatus.status === 'loading' ? <ShowLoader /> : data.map(user => <div key={user.id} onClick={() => deleteUser(user.id)}> {user.name} </div>)}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the useFetch inside your deleteUser hook . That is against the rules of hooks because hooks always need to be at the top inside your functional component .

What you can do instead is you can pass an additional argument called shouldRefetch to your customHook and add it as a dependency in your useEffect .

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export interface APIStatus {
  status: "loading" | "error" | "done";
}

// add shouldRefetch as the argument to the custom hook
export const useFetch = (api, params, shouldRefetch) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [apiStatus, setApiStatus] = useState(null);
  const [isSignedIn] = getSignInStatus();

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    setApiStatus({ status: "loading" });
    try {
      const { data } = await api(params);
      setData(data);
    } catch (err) {
      setApiStatus({ status: "error" });
    } finally {
      setApiStatus({ status: "done" });
    }
  }, [api]);

  // Add the shouldRefetch as an dependency and fire the API call when it is true
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSignedIn || shouldRefetch) fetchData();
  }, [isSignedIn, shouldRefetch]);

  return { apiStatus, data };
};

//App.tsx
export const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [shouldRefetch, setShouldRefetch] = useState(false);
  const { apiStatus, data } = useFetch(
    apis.fetchUsers,
    "limit=100",
    shouldRefetch
  );

  const deleteUser = (id) => {
    // delete the user

    // now set the shouldRefetch state to true
    setShouldRefetch(true);
  };

  // when the API status is done or error and the shouldRefetch is true then change it to false
  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      (apiStatus.status === "done" || apiStatus.status === "error") &&
      shouldRefetch
    ) {
      setShouldRefetch(false);
    }
  }, [apiStatus.status, shouldRefetch]);

  return (
    <>
      {apiStatus.status === "loading" ? (
        <ShowLoader />
      ) : (
        data.map((user) => (
          <div key={user.id} onClick={() => deleteUser(user.id)}>
            {" "}
            {user.name}{" "}
          </div>
        ))
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the help. But how will I handle the `deleteUser` functionality. I want to use the `useFetch` hook for deletion but if I use it inside deleteUser() function, I won't be able to show `<ShowLoader />` component while delete API is in progress?

Comment: Okay got it . In that case i think you need to have something similar to this - https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations . Where your hook should expose a function which can be called at the later point in time . In your case when deleting the user . If you have the privilege to add additional tools , then i would highly recommend trying our react-query . Because it does the exact same thing which you are looking for but in much more efficient way as it takes care of caching , refetching etc .

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I will look into this :)